# Writing a JSON string that enables passing an argument in double quotes to subprocess.call

Tags: python, json, subprocess

Code Snippet:

```
json_string='{"job1" : ["echo","\\"hello world\\""]}'
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
subprocess.call([parsed_json["job1"][0],parsed_json["job1"][1]])
```

Output:
`"hello world"`

When I print `parsed_json["job1"][0]` and `parsed_json["job1"][1]`, I get `echo` and `"hello world"` as outputs, respectively.

But when I type this command directly into the terminal, the output is different!

Commands in terminal:

```
echo "hello world"
```

or

```
echo hello world
```

The output for both the above commands is:
`hello world`

How do I rewrite the JSON string such that I can run the first terminal command (`echo "hello world"`) using subprocess.call function?

Comment: What produces `json_string`? Seems like it should contain `["echo", "hello world"]` instead. Otherwise, what would you expect `["echo", "\"hello world\" \"second string\""]` to do?

Comment: I wrote the `json_string`. ["echo", "hello world"] works fine and is the equivalent of the command `echo hello world`. I'm just curious to know how I can write the equivalent JSON string for the command `echo "hello world"`. I didn't understand the 2nd part of your question. ["echo", "\"hello world\"] does not let me compile the program properly. I read that other people have faced similar situations with the json.loads function.

Comment: `["echo", "hello world"]` *is* the equivalent of `echo "hello world"`. The shell interprets the quotes. When using `subprocess.call`, with a list of arguments, no shell is involved.